# KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED Ntoskernl.exe after hibernation

Tags: bsod, hibernate

When my computer comes back from hibernation, and after some minutes, I have a BSOD
KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
ntoskrnl.exe+3dda20

I did use windbg to check, and I have no clue what is causing that.

STACK_TEXT:
ffff8401`92764158 fffff807`64f00c3e : 00000000`0000001e ffffffff`c0000005 fffff807`64c369ae 00000000`00000000 : nt+0x3dda20
ffff8401`92764160 00000000`0000001e : ffffffff`c0000005 fffff807`64c369ae 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff : nt+0x500c3e
ffff8401`92764168 ffffffff`c0000005 : fffff807`64c369ae 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8401`92764720 : 0x1e
ffff8401`92764170 fffff807`64c369ae : 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8401`92764720 fffff807`64f00c1c : 0xffffffff`c0000005 ffff8401`92764178 00000000`00000000 : ffffffff`ffffffff ffff8401`92764720 fffff807`64f00c1c fffff807`64de68e2 : nt+0x2369ae

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
fffff80764d84f1e-fffff80764d84f21  4 bytes - nt!MiFreeUltraMapping+32
[ a0 7d fb f6:c0 ae 5d bb ]
fffff80764de1230-fffff80764de1234  5 bytes - nt!KiCallUserMode+220 (+0x5c312)
[ ff e1 cc cc cc:e8 8b 3e 64 00 ]
9 errors : !nt (fffff80764d84f1e-fffff80764de1234)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

---

It looks to be memory corruption on resume hibernate, but I do not understand why I do not have any issue when using the computer before running hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Get memtest86.exe  ([www.memtest86.com](http://www.memtest86.com)), make a bootable USB Key for it and run several (2 or 3) passes to test memory completely.

Check the version you get (for UEFI boot - newer version) or non-UEFI boot - older version)

Also, update your BIOS and Power Drivers. Use the computer vendor's Hardware Update app and do all drivers.

Finally when this is done, see if Hibernate works properly. Suspend is also a good option. I use Suspend instead of Hibernate.

For your hardware, make sure CPU and memory are set to standard manufacturer's settings.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. This is an Gigabyte AORUS board X570  + 4000 Mhz qualified RAM brand new, overclocked to 3800 MHZ. I never have any issue when booted from a reset, but comes after hibernation. I'm using the latest  BIOS version available.

Comment: Try standard settings for memory and CPU.

Comment: I need to check whether I have increased RAM voltage ... but what puzzles me, it is always after hibernation, crash adress always the same ntoskrnl + 3dda20 with the 5 bsod I can see. May be a buggy driver ?

Comment: I think either your hardware is not set to default settings, or, if you updated all drivers (I know you have BIOS up to date) then a driver may have a bug. I would re-update all drivers.

Comment: Tested with memtest86 for 5hours, in overclocked and non overclocked mode  : zero error, so this is not a memory hardware issue. Updated the nvidia drivers to the latest... let's see.

Comment: Video drivers updated. But the same occurs, still the same bsod from ntoskrnl.exe+3dda20, always the same address in stack